# macFUSE giving mount_macfuse: mount point ... is itself on a macFUSE volume - Apple M1 macOS 12.3

Tags: apple-m1, fuse, sshfs, osxfuse

This issue is driving me crazy. I keep getting an error:
"macFUSE giving mount_macfuse: mount point ... is itself on a macFUSE volume "

where ... is my mount point

when i run sshfs --version i clearly dont have the correct FUSE version coming up, according to my install i have 4.2.4 installed under system prferences with macOS 12.3

i tried installing FUSE from the .dmg, i removed it, tried installing via brew.. restart after restart. upgraded the OS to latest. Homebrew 3.4.2

output from terminal when running "sshfs --version"

```
SSHFS version 2.5 (OSXFUSE SSHFS 2.5.0)
FUSE library version: 2.9.9
fuse: no mount point
```

Ive never been able to mount an external host fs using the simple command:

```
sudo sshfs hosta:/ ~/Desktop/2 -o defer_permissions,auto_cache,reconnect,volname=hostamnt
```

can anyone shed some light on this issue?

Answer (score 8):

For me, the problem was in the selection of options. The following finally worked, based on [this](https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/issues/384):

```
mkdir ~/sshfs_mount

sshfs -o kill_on_unmount,reconnect,allow_other,defer_permissions,direct_io,IdentityFile=~/.ssh/id_rsa the_user@10.15.32.17:/home/the_user/ ~/sshfs_mount

# <<< the folder is mounted and visible in the finder >>

umount ~/sshfs_mount
```

P.S Remove `,IdentityFile=~/.ssh/id_rsa` to match your connection configs

Comment: Thanks.  So many of the google searches reference OSX version back to Leopard.  This was the first clear answer that worked well.  Greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're a saviour!

Answer (score 5):

Just unmount the folder you specified in the local and try again, it mounts each time even if the file changes, so make sure to unmount if you want to try again

```
umount /your_directory/
```

In this case

```
umount /tmp/fuse
```

If it is showing error again, you can try

```
diskutil umount force /your_directory/
```

Comment: It's `umount`, not `unmount`.

Answer (score 4):

Heads up with macOS Ventura (beta), I had the same error.

It looks like for some reason I wasn't able to mount in a folder in my user directory. Doing it in `/tmp` worked fine though. This may be some new directory protection thing.

So slightly amending Oleg O's great answer above and reusing their options, this worked for me:

```bash
mkdir /tmp/fuse

sshfs -o kill_on_unmount,reconnect,allow_other,defer_permissions,direct_io,IdentityFile=~/.ssh/id_rsa ubuntu@192.168.205.13:/home/ubuntu/ /tmp/fuse

umount /tmp/fuse
```